# Posting to Twitter account from Django

Tags: python, django, twitter

I have an application where you write a short story (maximum 130 chars) and post it on the site.

However, what I want to do is to add a specific hashtag in the end of the story and post it on a specific Twitter account in the same time as it's posted on the site.

What is the best way to deal with this action? Is there any apps out there that I could use? I read about Twython but it seems to contain of a lot of things I don't need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something minimal, checkout https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter. Here is an example https://gist.github.com/damilare/4435261

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaking, [Tango](https://github.com/tBaxter/Tango) (a django CMS) has a feature like (**auto-tweet**) this built in. Maybe its way of dealing with twitter can inspire you.

Check the remark in its dependencies

> vobject django-allauth Python-Twitter (if you want to auto-tweet news items)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that you don't want to import all of twython because you'd only be using some of it? If so then you could still used twython but only import some of it:

```
from twython import <thing you want>
```

I wasn't quite sure what you were asking, but other twitter API libraries for python include:

- [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)
- [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter)
- [TweetPony](https://github.com/Mezgrman/TweetPony)
- [Python Twitter Tools](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter)
- [twitter-gobject](https://github.com/tchx84/twitter-gobject)
- [TwitterSearch](https://github.com/ckoepp/TwitterSearch)
- [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)

Test these out if you like and tell us which is best,

Hope this helped,

Jake Zachariah Nixon.